# In the 2000 miniseries, "Dune", what does Gurney say during the sparring scene on Caladan?

Tags: dune

This has been bothering me for 20 years.  I even owned the DVD and watched it a lot. During the sparring scene on Caladan, Paul says that he's not in the mood for the fight.  Gurney says:

> "Not in the mood? Mood is a thing for [something] young pup.  Mood is not for fighting"

What is that [something]?  The best I've got is "Cattle and Women", but that...really doesn't sound right.

Comment: The quote from the book is: "What has mood to do with it? You fight when the neccesity arises - no matter the mood. Mood's a thing for cattle or making love or playing the baliset. It's not for fighting." - so you're probably pretty close

Comment: Honestly I've never turned them on and now I don't have the DVD anymore :-P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the DVD subtitles

> *"Mood is **a thing for cattle and women**, young pup. Mood is not for fighting,"*

This well reflects the line from the source novel

> “Mood?” Halleck’s voice betrayed his outrage even through the shield’s filtering. “What has mood to do with it? You fight when the necessity arises — no matter the mood! **Mood’s a thing for cattle or making love or playing the baliset. It’s not for fighting.”**

Gurney is simply suggesting that '*being in the mood*' is something that's more appropriate for people (or cows) with ample time to spare. It's what you have the liberty to exercise when your life isn't on the line.

Comment: You mean I was right!? That was unexpected...I always thought it was something a lot more profound

Comment: in the context of the scene (especially in the novel) - I think it is fairly profound @MichaelStachowsky -  It's a great lesson Halleck gives Paul

Comment: How did the cattle on planet Caladan communicate?

Comment: @IanThompson - By taking off their snorkels and mooing

Comment: Indeed. "Mood" is a thing for cattle, after all. I'll get my stillsuit.